# Mocking Controller dependency in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I am trying to mock my controller using nestjs createTestingModule and I have added overrider provider to mock the service but it still giving me this error

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I also tried added the other dependencies too but the error is same

Here is my controller.ts file

```
import {Body, NotFoundException, OnModuleInit, Param, Patch} from "@nestjs/common";
import {BitvavoService} from "./bitvavo.service";
import {DeleteMethod, GetMethod, PostMethod, PatchMethod} from "../../../../global/operations";
import {ApiController} from "../../../../utils/endpoints/api-controller.decorator";
import bitvavo, {BitvavoOrderResponse} from "bitvavo";
import {Repository} from "../../../repository/repository";
import {BitvavoTarget} from "./bitvavo-target";
import {RepositoryFactory} from "../../../repository/repository-factory.service";
import {CollectionNames} from "../../../repository/collection-names";
import {ProducerTargetBindingService} from "../../producer-target-binding/producer-target-binding.service";
import {User, UserClass} from "../../../../utils/endpoints/user.decorator";
import {Permissions} from "../../../../utils/endpoints/permissions.decorator";
import {Permission} from "../../../../utils/permission.enum";
import {EncryptionService} from "../../../encrypt/encrypt.service";
import {
  BitvavoBalanceDto,
  BitvavoPlaceOrderDto,
  BitvavoSingleTargetResponse,
  CreateBitvavoTargetDto,
  UpdateBitvavoTargetDto,
  ChangeBitvavoTargetMode,
  SellSingleBot
} from "./bitvavo-dtos";
import {toTargetDto} from "../target-dto";
import {ApiBotService} from "../../signal-producers/implementers/api-bot/api-bot.service";

const getBalances = async function (target: BitvavoTarget, decryptedKey: string, decryptedSecret: string) {
  try {
    const client = createBitvavoClient(decryptedKey, decryptedSecret);
    return (await client.balance({})).map(balanceToDto);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

@ApiController("signal-targets/bitvavo")
export class BitvavoController implements OnModuleInit {
  private repository: Repository<BitvavoTarget>;

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.repository = await this.repositoryFactory.create(BitvavoTarget);
  }

  constructor(
    private bitvavoService: BitvavoService,
    private repositoryFactory: RepositoryFactory,
    private producerTargetBindingService: ProducerTargetBindingService,
    private encryptionService: EncryptionService,
    private apiBotService: ApiBotService
  ) {}

  @PostMethod()
  @Permissions(Permission.CreateTargets)
  async create(@Body() targetDto: CreateBitvavoTargetDto, @User() user: UserClass) {
    const userTargets = await this.repository.getAll(user.sub);
    const safeModel = {
      ...targetDto,
      name: targetDto.name ? targetDto.name : `Bitvavo Wallet ${userTargets.length + 1}`,
      key: this.encryptionService.encrypt(targetDto.key),
      secret: this.encryptionService.encrypt(targetDto.secret)
    };
    await this.repository.create({...safeModel, userId: user.sub, positions: []}); // TODO some unique checking stuff
  }

  @GetMethod()
  @Permissions(Permission.ReadTargets)
  async get(@User() user: UserClass) {
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      return await this.repository.getAllInternal();
    }
    return await this.repository.getAll(user.sub);
  }

  @GetMethod("/:id")
  @Permissions(Permission.ReadTargets)
  async getOne(@Param("id") targetId: string, @User() user: UserClass): Promise<BitvavoSingleTargetResponse> {
    let targetOpt;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      targetOpt = await this.bitvavoService.getOneInternal(targetId);
    } else {
      targetOpt = await this.bitvavoService.getOne(targetId, user.sub);
    }
    if (!targetOpt) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    const {bindings, target} = targetOpt;

    const decryptedKey = this.encryptionService.decrypt(target.key);
    const decryptedSecret = this.encryptionService.decrypt(target.secret);
    const balances = await getBalances(target, decryptedKey, decryptedSecret);

    return {
      target: toTargetDto({type: CollectionNames.Bitvavo, name: target.name, _id: target._id, targetMode: target.targetMode}),
      // producer: mapProducerToDto(producer),
      balances: balances,
      bindings: bindings
    };
  }

  @PostMethod("/:id/placeOrder")
  async placeOrder(@Param("id") id: string, @Body() body: BitvavoPlaceOrderDto, @User() user: UserClass): Promise<BitvavoOrderResponse> {
    let target;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneById(id, user.sub);
    }
    if (!target) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return await this.bitvavoService.handleSignal(target, body);
  }

  @Patch("/:id")
  @Permissions(Permission.EditTargets)
  async update(@Param("id") id: string, @User() user: UserClass, @Body() targetDto: UpdateBitvavoTargetDto) {
    let target;
    let key;
    let secret;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelById(id, user.sub);
    }
    if (!target) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    if (targetDto.key) {
      key = this.encryptionService.encrypt(targetDto.key);
    } else {
      key = target.key;
    }
    if (targetDto.secret) {
      secret = this.encryptionService.encrypt(targetDto.secret);
    } else {
      secret = target.secret;
    }
    Object.assign(target, {...targetDto, key, secret});
    await target.save();
  }

  @DeleteMethod("/:id")
  @Permissions(Permission.DeleteTargets)
  async deleteTarget(@Param("id") id: string, @User() user: UserClass) {
    let target;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelById(id, user.sub);
    }
    if (!target) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    await this.repository.deleteById(id);
    await this.producerTargetBindingService.deleteAllForTarget({id: target.id, type: CollectionNames.Bitvavo});
  }

  @PostMethod("/:id/sellto/:base")
  @Permissions(Permission.EditTargets)
  async sellAllForTarget(@Param("id") id: string, @Param("base") base: string, @User() user: UserClass) {
    let target;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelById(id, user.sub);
    }
    if (!target) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    await this.producerTargetBindingService.deleteAllForTarget({id: target.id, type: CollectionNames.Bitvavo});
    await this.bitvavoService.sellAllToAsset(target, base);
  }

  @PatchMethod("/:id/changeTargetMode")
  @Permissions(Permission.EditTargets)
  async changeTargetMode(@Param("id") id: string, @Body() targetDto: ChangeBitvavoTargetMode, @User() user: UserClass) {
    let target;
    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelById(id, user.sub);
    }
    if (!target) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    Object.assign(target, {...target, targetMode: targetDto.targetMode});
    await target.save();
  }

  @PostMethod("/:id/stopBot/:base")
  @Permissions(Permission.EditTargets)
  async sellSingleTarget(@Param("id") id: string, @Param("base") base: string, @Body() body: SellSingleBot, @User() user: UserClass) {
    let target;
    let producer;

    if (user.permissions.includes(Permission.AdminTargets)) {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelByIdInternal(id);
    } else {
      target = await this.repository.getOneModelById(id, user.sub);
    }

    producer = await this.apiBotService.getOneModelInternal(body.botName);

    if (!target || !producer) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    await this.producerTargetBindingService.deleteSingleForTarget(
      {id: target.id, type: CollectionNames.Bitvavo},
      {id: producer._id, type: CollectionNames.ApiBot}
    );
    await this.bitvavoService.sellAllToAsset(target, base);
  }
}

export const createBitvavoClient = (key: string, secret: string) => {
  return bitvavo().options({
    APIKEY: key,
    APISECRET: secret,
    ACCESSWINDOW: 10000,
    RESTURL: "https://api.bitvavo.com/v2",
    WSURL: "wss://ws.bitvavo.com/v2/",
    DEBUGGING: false
  });
};

const balanceToDto = (balance: {symbol: string; available: string; inOrder: string}): BitvavoBalanceDto => {
  return balance as BitvavoBalanceDto;
};
```

Here is my controller.spec.ts

```
import {BitvavoService} from "./bitvavo.service";
import {Test} from "@nestjs/testing";
import {BitvavoController} from "./bitvavo.controller";

describe("Bitvavo Controller", () => {
  let controller: BitvavoController;

  const mockValue = {};

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [BitvavoController],
      providers: [BitvavoService]
    })
      .overrideProvider(BitvavoService)
      .useValue({onModuleInit: jest.fn(), handleSignal: jest.fn(), sellAllToAsset: jest.fn(), getOne: jest.fn(), getOneInternal: jest.fn()})
      .compile();
  });

  it("test", () => {});
});
```

Comment: did `providers: [ { provide: BitvavoController, useValue: yourStub } ]` works?

Comment: I tried with BitvavoService as provide but didn't work

Comment: oh, yeah. My bad. Well, this is pretty much standard. That's weird.